# EF core - same statement has different results in query and after fetching data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Title may be misleading, here's what happens:

```cs
var resp = await DbContext.Events
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(t => t.Id == eventId)
    .Select(t => new EventGeneralInfoDTO
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        IsRedirectionAvailable = t.Status == (int)EventStatus.Open &&
        (t.StartDate.HasValue && ((DateTimeOffset)t.StartDate).ToUnixTimeSeconds() < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds())
            && (t.EndDate.HasValue && ((DateTimeOffset)t.EndDate).ToUnixTimeSeconds() > DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds())
        && !t.HasNewVersion
    }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

here, IsRedirectionAvailable is false (should be true however). But if I do something like this:

```cs
var test = DbContext.Events.First(a => a.Id == eventId);
resp.IsRedirectionAvailable = test.Status == (int)EventStatus.Open &&
            (test.StartDate.HasValue && ((DateTimeOffset)test.StartDate).ToUnixTimeSeconds() < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds())
                && (test.EndDate.HasValue && ((DateTimeOffset)test.EndDate).ToUnixTimeSeconds() > DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds())
            && !test.HasNewVersion;
```

it is true. I think some of the expressions can't be translated to sql, but I though that when it happens, query throws an exception. Was it changed in 7.0? If no, why am I getting different results?

Edit 1. Generated SQL:

```
  Executed DbCommand (1,902ms) [Parameters=[@__eventId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT TOP(1) [t].[Id], [t].[EventId], [t].[RfxId], [t].[Name], [t].[OrganizationName], [t].[OrganizationId], CASE
      WHEN [t].[EnvelopeOpeingDate] IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END, CAST([t].[EnvelopeOpeingDate] AS datetimeoffset), CASE
      WHEN [t].[EndDate] IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END, CAST([t].[EndDate] AS datetimeoffset), CASE
      WHEN [t].[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END, CAST([t].[StartDate] AS datetimeoffset), CASE
      WHEN [t].[TemporaryComplinceDate] IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END, CAST([t].[TemporaryComplinceDate] AS datetimeoffset), [t].[BudgetCategoryCode], [t].[Address], (
      SELECT TOP(1) [l].[CPVCode]
      FROM [LotInfo] AS [l]
      WHERE [t].[Id] = [l].[PublicEventId]), CAST([t].[EventType] AS int), CASE
      WHEN [t].[Status] = 1 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END, CASE
      WHEN [t].[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END, CAST(SYSUTCDATETIME() AS datetimeoffset), CASE
      WHEN [t].[EndDate] IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END, CASE
      WHEN [t].[HasNewVersion] = CAST(0 AS bit) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
  END
  FROM [Events] AS [t]
  WHERE [t].[Id] = @__eventId_0
```

(I omitted unrelated fields from code, that's why query is bigger)
Apparently, it ignores fields that are not columns (I believe it wasn't like that before, maybe I'm wrong), in this case there is no IsRedirectionAvailable column. Is this new thing or I just never encountered it?

Edit 2. Yes, it was because of DateTimeOffset conversion. However, I expected to get an exception (since EF Core 3.0 if your query can't be translated to SQL query, it throwed an exception). I didn't get it, so I was thinking that the query is fine. Looks like this behavior was changed in later versions, and you no longer get an exception. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Add generated SQL to the question.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your code immediately. If I was debugging this code, I would check what's exactly coming from the database by selecting all the fields that affect the value of one calculated field you care about and go from there.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv added, it helped, but I'm not sure if this behavior is ok, I think I selected fields that are not columns before and it was ok

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev did that, it works fine, it doesn't work as expected when calculated field is computed in a query

Comment: Add SQL from first LINQ query. What you have posted is not interesting for analysis.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it is SQL from first LINQ query with extra fields. If you want, I can remove properties that you don't see in the code, but it's the same

Comment: Oh, my fault. Bad LINQ query formatting.

Comment: Well, put `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` into local variable and use this variable in query. Then compare results.

Comment: @Jamil there's no point to the conversions to Unix Timestamp or the explicit casts to `DateTimeOffset`. What are the types of `StartDate` and `EndDate`? Are they `datetimeoffset` or not? If not do they contain local or UTC time? You should be able to write just `t.StartDate < DateTimeOffset.Now`. All the expressions are converted to SQL, which as no problem comparing nullable values with other values

Comment: There's no reason to use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` if the fields are `datetimeoffset` either. If they aren't, there's no reason to use `DateTimeOffset` at all. If the fields contain UTC time, compare them to `DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: Is `Status` an enum? In that case its type could be `EventStatus` eliminating the cast. Which isn't needed anyway, enums are just labeled integers. The entire condition should be `t.Status == EventStatus.Open &&
t.StartDate < DateTimeOffset.Now && t.EndDate> DateTimeOffset.Now && !t.HasNewVersion)`

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using? The SQL query shows that EF can't translate your `SELECT` to SQL so it loads the individual elements. Many of them are useless, like `CASE WHEN [t].[StartDate] IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)`. EF can't eliminate them though, because that's what the query asked for

Comment: For your first linq, does it work fine? Because implicit client evaluation has been disabled from EF Core 3.

Comment: I edited the question. Looks like I need to read changes to EF Core, since I didn't expect it to not throw an exception. Thanks.